finding overlaid text in html from a website
I'm using Selenium to browse sites and locate text overlaid in html on an image. But I have problems, how can I correctly identify the superimposed text on a web page in a unique way, without taking icons, logos etc. into consideration?
I use Selenium with ChromeDriver, visit the website.
filters images to remove logos or icons, searches for overlapping text and collects image-text pairs.
The problem is that it doesn't correctly identify all the css attributes to locate the overlapping text.

The problem I'm having is related to parsing CSS styles to determine whether a text is actually overlaid on an image. Despite checking the position and z-index CSS styles, there are cases where overlapping text is not detected correctly. CSS styles can be very complex and vary widely, making it difficult to accurately capture overlapping text.

Examples of Problematic Situations
Texts with position: absolute or fixed: They are not always captured correctly, especially if the z-index is not set explicitly.
Dynamic CSS Styles: Pages that use JavaScript to dynamically change styles can cause problems detecting overlapping text.
Using Pseudo-Elements: Overlapping texts via CSS pseudo-elements (::before, ::after) are not always detected.
Complex Overlays: Texts that are part of complex overlays with many layers of parent and sibling elements can be difficult to detect correctly.

you could edit question and put text from comments in question

If I was going to do this I would: Search for all <img /> tags in the HTML, and measure their top and bottom positions using offsetTop and offsetLeft (ie: position relative to the whole webpage). Then I would search for all text-like tags (I guess all <p> tags? It depends on what type of text I'm looking for), find their top and bottom positions, and compare to the <img /> tags. It doesn't sound perfect but it may be a start
